# React Axios: отправка данных между страницами localhost

Tags: reactjs, axios, localhost

У меня есть React приложения, которое ещё находится в разработке. Я сделал регистрацию пользователей с помощью firebase и мне удалось создать для каждого пользователя, вне зависимости от сущности (водитель или клиент), uuid, который я поместил в адресную строку. Грубо говоря ссылка на страницу выглядит так:

```
http://localhost:5173/user-way?uuid=admin
```

Тоже самое для водителя, только вместо `user-way` `driver-way`

В компоненте, который отвечает за прогрузку страницы клиента, я получаю введенные клиентом данные. Эти данные нужно отправить водителям (для этого я создал отдельный компонент, который получает uuid всех водителей, и вызвал этот компонент в UserWay, компонент страницы клиента. Возникает вопрос, если я захочу отправить данные всем водителям с помощью axios, данные дойдут до водителей или из-за локального сервера коннект между страницами невозможен.

Понимаю, вопрос глупый, извините за потраченное время, и заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Любой запрос с клиента идет только на сервер. Сам сервер не может по своей инициативе отправить запрос клиенту. Двустороннюю связь можно держать сокетами, пуш-уведомлениями или [SSE](https://learn.javascript.ru/server-sent-events). Сокет и sse требуют что бы клиент был подкючен, пуши можно отправлять без подключенного клинта.

Comment: Кстати, если надо, что бы страницы одного домена локально обменивались инфой(сайт открыт в нескольких вкладках), то можно данные сохранять в localstorage и повесить слушатель на изменение данных. Но опять же, это работать будет только локально в рамках 1 браузера.

Comment: @SwaD, понял, спасибо